# How to check a closest value in a table and it need to be smaller than the given number?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Let's assume that I have a number and a table.

```lua
myNumber = 475
myTable = {400,350,450,500,300,476}
function ClosestValue(number,value)
--What do I write here?
end
```

How do I make the ClosestValue() function return 450 but not 476 or any another value?
Thanks for answering.

Comment: iterate over the numbers and store the best number found so far, (initialize with -math.huge or something) update that when smaller than the given number but larger than the found one

Comment: if I give you a few balls of different size. what would you do to get me the closest smaller ball? my toddler son could figure out that logic. come on. why are you asking a question here instead of using your brain? you won't learn anything if your brain instantly relays any workload to StackOverflow. we can help you to translate that into Lua but at least present what is necessary

Comment: I've tried many method but its really buggy when applying to game environment. That's why im here to ask for a better method which I will improve it later on. I use around 4 loops to check its value and its sometime return the first index value, sometime return the smallest value in the table.

Comment: If you use more than one loop your have done something wrong. Post your progress so far as Piglet suggested.